# Cannot access localhost server in Win-7-64

Tags: apache, windows-7-x64, appserver

I installed appservnertwork as default and I cannot access to server using localhost but it works using 127.0.0.1
Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to do run   nslookup localhost     ? (Please notify @ me, I don't check for answers)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve it. 
Open the file "hosts" at system32/drivers/etc as Admin (right click and open as admin the editor)
The modify the file or uncomment the line where says 127.0.0.1 localhost